# Convert postgres sql queries into oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I am trying to speed up a random selection query in Oracle and found this [blog](https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/how-to-sample-rows-in-sql-273x-faster). I am not able to convert their following Postgres queries in oracle:

```
    select * from users
      where 
        random() < 200 / (select count(1) from logs)::float
      order by random()
      limit 100;
```

and

```
   select * from users
     where id in (
       select round(random() * 21e6)::integer as id
       from generate_series(1, 110)
       group by id -- Discard duplicates
       )
     limit 100;
```

How would this queries look like in oracle?

Comment: Both support `FETCH FIRST` instead of `LIMIT`. And I suppose `CAST` instead of `::`.

Comment: Can you please post your current oracle query

Comment: What about using `tablesample` to sample rows from a table?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I know that there are many ways (and many posts) on how to use native sampling oracle techniques. I am interested in comparing them against  the two queries above in terms of performance, therefore I need first to write them in oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such queries :

```
 select * from 
 (
 select u.*, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) as rn 
   from users u
  where 
    dbms_random.value < 200 / (select count(1) from logs)
  )
  where rn <= 100;
```

and

```
select * from
(
select u.*, row_number() over (order by 1) as rn
  from users u
 where id in (
              select round(dbms_random.value * 21e6) as id                    
                from dual
             connect by level <= 110  
             )
 )
 where rn <= 100;
```

If your Oracle DB's version is 12c, you can replace `where rn <= 100` parts with `fetch first 100 rows only` and remove `rn` ( which are made up of `row_number()` function ) columns in the subqueries.

Comment: I don't get from the original blog post, and from your answer, what is `logs` in the first query, I thought some specific Postgres thing..

Comment: @giotto I think they are not platform spesific structures, such as dictionary views, but user-created ordinary tables.

Comment: Any clue on why I get `SQL Error [904] [42000]: ORA-00904: "ID": invalid identifier` error if I run the second query?

Comment: @giotto seems you have no such column `ID` in `users` table. You might rename in the subquery to a name which is a column of that table.